# ADB tcpip command doesnot work in windows without cable

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I followed the following steps

1. ADB tcpip 5555
   its shows message restarting in TCP mode port: 5556
2. ADB connect 192.168.1.76
   it shows message connected to 192.168.1.76
3. ADB devices
   ce04u3hdtdn       device
   192.168.1.76:5555 device
4. now I unplug my usb

no devices gets displayed and code in eclipse does not work

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps

1. In your terminal run `adb devices` (be sure device is connected via USB)
2. Then run `adb tcpip 5555`
3. After that to connect use this command `adb connect 192.168.1.76:5555`

After that you can remove USB

Comment: its showing connected  when i run adb connect 192.168.1.76:5555 but  when  i removed my usb and run adb devices in cmd no devices deteced

Answer (score 0):

Run the following. Last step is imp

```
adb kill-server
+ adb kill-server
root# adb tcpip 5555
+ adb tcpip 5555
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
root# adb connect 192.168.43.1:5555
+ adb connect 192.168.43.1:5555
connected to 192.168.43.1:5555
adb -s 192.168.43.1:5555 shell
root# adb -s 192.168.43.1:5555 shell
+ adb -s 192.168.43.1:5555 shell
/#  <--- connection successful.
```

run `adb -s 192.168.43.1:5555 shell`     & then remove USB